# Packages installer (for Mac) script execution fails

Tags: macos, installation, package

I have been unsuccessful in getting Packages V1.1.2 (within OSX 10.9.5) in either bundle or flat mode to fire any sort of script—-even a simple test script that simply beeps:

```
#!/bin/sh
osa "beep 1"
exit 0
```

The package and script have been code-signed and verified, and the script permissions are set to what I take to be the correct permissions using chmod u+rwx. What is frustrating is that I have an older Package installation file that executes its script just fine. What can I be overlooking?

I was advised to look at the install log and found the following:

> Executing script "./preinstall" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.dm4H07/Scripts/com.mygreatcompany.pkg.Test.FMBtOk
>   PackageKit: *** Couldn't posix_spawn: error 8

Perhaps Sandbox is the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was something wrong with my shell script. I remade a new shell script, pasting the original content except the "she-bang" part. That I hand-typed. I noted that unlike my original shell script, the new one showed up in my desktop with a white icon--not black like my previous script file. Recently I had been playing around with C programming and made some change to my command line tool to make it compile the C. Whatever change I made to terminal (by pasting in some code I grabbed from a blog that discussed how to get the Mac Terminal to compile C) may have been the culprit. I should add that I also reinstalled my Packages application.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue where copy pasting a script from a blog was failing  with "Couldn't posix_spawn: error 8". Recreating the script worked.